# how to send an email alert to an account owner's manager

Tags: workflow, email-template, email-alert

I am trying to configure an email alert to be able to send out to the manager of the account owner of an account. To this end I have set up a field on the account object that stores the email of the account owner's manager (e.g., owner.manager.email) however I am unable to select this field from the email alert's related email list of fields in the email alert configuration screen. At the risk of repeating myself, I need to set up the email alert so that it sends an email to the manager of the account owner.

Comment: Did you try to use the Account Roles? I know sending email to it form flow is tricky.

Answer (score 2):

If you setup the Account manager field on account object as a lookup you can access it through the Related user filter and send email to the related user ( Account manager lookup field)

[image]

Comment: I want the field to automatically store the account manager's manager value is some form that I can then set an email alert against. Your sol'n seems to require that a user sets the value in the field by using the lookup rather than using a formula to store the value of the account mgr's mgr.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a formula field to hold the email address it will not be available, instead you would need to create an email field, which you could set with a workflow rule.