# Sending Alerts to account owner's Manager

Tags: process-builder, email-alert, alert

I want to send an email to the account owner's manager.
I saw another question answered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47272/how-to-send-an-email-alert-to-an-account-owners-manager)

I created a lookup field on the account that looks at the user's manager. ( It updates through process builder) but I don't see it under the related user when I go to assign the alert.
[image]

I also tried to do it through email, as suggested [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jkxwQAA). ( i created an email field that populates with the manager's email through process builder) the field also does not show up.
[image]

Comment: Hi Hamza,  you have mentioned that you had created lookup field on account   but in your screenshot  i am seeing opportunity owner as available selection.   if  email will be triggered based on opportunity update  you should create lookup field on oppounity.

Comment: In addition to the above comment by @gauravsharma, there's also a relationship for `Opportunity.Account.OwnerId__r` which may be what you need to look for (and are referring to) since the Opp Owner may not necessarily be the same user as the Account Owner.

Comment: Hi @gauravsharma Thank you for pointing that out. it turns out that was the problem, I created the fields on the wrong object. now I see them when I created them under the opportunity object.